# CakePHP Javascript OnSelect Dropdown

Tags: javascript, cakephp

I have a bit of a problem and I'm not sure if javascript is the solution for this. Anyway, I have 4 fields in my forms which are a dropdown field, file upload field, and 2 text input field.

My form currently implements a bootstrap validator, which is using a javascript. This is a snippet of it.

```
$('#uploadFileForm')
            .bootstrapValidator({
                live: 'enabled',
                fields: {
                    'data[Upload][uploadtype]': {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: 'Choose Upload Type'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    'data[Upload][browsefile]': {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: 'Choose a file to upload'
                            },
                            file: {
                                extension: 'pdf',
                                type: 'application/pdf',
                                maxSize: 5120 * 5120 * 5120 * 5120 * 5120,
                                message: 'The file must be in .pdf format and must not exceed 5MB in size'
                            }
                        }
                    };
```

Anyway, this one is working. What I want to do is the file upload field will adjust its validator according to what was chosen in the dropdown field.

For example, let's say I chose the 'PDF' in the dropdown, the code above will trigger and say 'The file must be in .pdf format and must not exceed 5MB in size', which is correct. But what if I chose 'Pictures' in the dropdown, how can I make the correct validator appear?

Is there any way that I can do this?

Thank you!

Comment: you have to check file type which is being uploaded and change the validation rule. Try to use CakePHP validations instead of javascript.

Comment: But I have a lot of input fields which uses the bootstrap validator. I don't want to change all of them? Is there a way to use javascript for that?

Comment: Try changing the validation rule for data[Upload][browsefile] dynamically when you select data[Upload][uploadtype]

Comment: So how do I do that?

Comment: Check [Dynamically change validation rules](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html) you can change the validation rules in your Model or the Controller.

You can do something like 
   if ($this->request->data['selection'] === '1')
      $this->validator()->add('username', 'required');